# What does rectangle is outside bounds mean

Tags: php, google-chrome

What does PPB_Graphics2D.PaintImageData: Rectangle is outside bounds mean?? I'm seeing it on almost every piece of code I inspect. The most recent code being

```
define("my consumer key");
define("my consumer secret");

$oauth = new OAuth(my consumer key, my consumer secret);

//The first item of business is getting a request token
$request_token_response = $oauth->getRequestToken('https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken');

if($request_token_response === FALSE) {
        throw new Exception("Failed fetching request token, response was:"
        . $oauth->getLastResponse());
} else {
        $request_token = $request_token_response;
}

print "Request Token:\n";
printf("    - oauth_token        = %s\n", $request_token['oauth_token']);
printf("    - oauth_token_secret = %s\n", $request_token['oauth_token_secret']);
print "\n";
```

I would love to know what this error means and how I could rid of it

Comment: there is nowhere in this code that I see an error like that could be thrown based on what you provided. What is happening exactly? What is this code anyway, it just looks like log in code using OAuth.

Comment: If I inspect the element it shows 2PPB_Graphics2D.PaintImageData: Rectangle is outside bounds. Btw, there is a fatal error being thrown w/the above code

Comment: Inspect as in the HTML??!?!? Are you seeing this error in the console in Firebug or Chrome developer tools? Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to be an error with the latest version of Google Chrome. We are seeing this issue on our site, and many others that feature flash content.

E.g.

- http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/
- http://edition.cnn.com/

Comment: Do you have anything to reference regarding the Chrome error?

Answer (score 1):

Then the error is in Javascript on the page not PHP. You are looking at entirely the wrong code.

Comment: In my site is happening with a swf player hidden to play songs.