# What is PPB_Graphics2D.PaintImageData: Rectangle is outside bounds. error in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser

In this page:

http://www.rockit.it/deniseproject/album/uninverse/20598

when I press "play" on the tracklist the browser starts rising errors. It seems only a Google Chrome issue.

Do you know how to stop those errors?
It seemes connected with the swf player used to listen to the music, it's controlled throught javascript and it's embedded with 1 pixel in width and 1 pixl in height.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have the same problem. I am not happy about the error log showing these errors, so looking into a fix.

Comment: I think is a flash issue, also see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12847210/what-does-rectangle-is-outside-bounds-mean

Comment: I get a similar issue but there's no Flash involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an internal log of Chromium PPAPI. Here's the link to the issue:
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=141609

Now it's fixed in current Chrome stable.